# Can I skip inputting optional function parameters in tcl?

Tags: tcl

I know I can make tcl functions with optional input parameters. So if you don't enter a value for those parameters they can take on the default value that you give them. My question is when I call a function with optional parameters is it possible to skip the input of some and enter others? Like if there are 2x optional parameters how would I enter a value for the second parameter rather than the first?

I haven't really tried anything specifically because I'm not sure how to get around this problem.

```
proc area { height width {normalization 1.0} {scaling 1.0} {
....
}


[area 3 4 3.5]
```

Is there a way I could call area without changing the default value for normalization, while entering a value for scaling?

If I wanted a scaling value of 3.5 I can't really enter it in without also entering a value for normalization?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct; if you want a scaling value of 3.5, you cannot enter it without also entering a value for normalization with the way the `proc` was written.

You can do something a bit more towards what you want to do with some tweaking (there's a whole [wiki article discussing about ways to do this](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Argument+Parsing%2C+a+discussion)). A quick example with an `array`:

```
proc area {height width args} {
    # Put the remaining parameters in an array, you might want to do validation checks before that
    array set options $args

    # If certain parameters are not provided, give default values
    if {"-normalization" ni [array names options]} {
        set options(-normalization) 1.0
    }
    if {"-scaling" ni [array names options]} {
        set options(-scaling) 1.0
    }

    puts "Normalization: $options(-normalization)"
    puts "Scaling: $options(-scaling)"
}

area 1 2 -normalization 3.5
# => Normalization: 3.5 
# => Scaling: 1.0

area 1 2 -scaling 3.5
# => Normalization: 1.0
# => Scaling: 3.5

area 1 2
# => Normalization: 1.0
# => Scaling: 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern I use is this:

```
proc area {height width args} {
    # The default values
    set defaults {-normalization 1.0 -scaling 1.0}
    # Merge with the actual arguments provided
    set params [dict merge $defaults $args]
    # Just extract the variables I care about using [dict update] with an empty body
    dict update params -normalization norm -scaling scale {}
    # Demonstrate what's been extracted
    puts "Parameters: $height $width $norm $scale"
}

area 2 3 -scaling 17.3
```

This isn't perfect since it doesn't warn/error about unexpected arguments, provide a discovery mechanism, or handle argument name abbreviation, but it's simple and cheap and fairly fast. There have been proposals for changing that (I'm aware of two TIPs: [457](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/457.md), [479](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/479.md)) but none have really gained traction so far; it's an area that is a tricky compromise between flexibility and performance.

(If you use the variable name as the actual parameter name and don't care at all about wrong arguments, you can just use `dict with` to do the extraction.)

---

A shorter version (using the same basic idea) might be:

```
proc area {height width args} {
    array set {} [dict merge {-normalization 1.0 -scaling 1.0} $args]
    puts "Parameters: $height $width $(-normalization) $(-scale)"
}
```

This uses the variable with the empty name as an array. Yes, that's legal (and relatively convenient) but I've never really warmed to it myself.

Comment: The key is that `args` is a special formal parameter to a procedure _when it is the last parameter._ It holds a list of all remaining arguments. Which we can reinterpret as a dictionary…

Answer (score 0):

> There have been proposals for changing that (I'm aware of two TIPs:
>   457, 479) but none have really gained traction so far.

If you are willing to use an established Tcl extension (https://next-scripting.org/), you can benefit from optional named parameters when implementing a `proc`:

```
package req nsf

nsf::proc area {height width {-normalization 1.0} {-scaling 1.0}} {
  puts "arguments: $height $width $normalization $scaling"
}

area 1 2 -normalization 3.5
# arguments: 1 2 3.5 1.0
area 1 2 -scaling 3.5
# arguments: 1 2 1.0 3.5
area 1 2
# arguments: 1 2 1.0 1.0
```